# Handoff renders two-factor authencation worthless?

Tags: mac, continuity, two-factor-authentication

I noticed that when I enabled two-factor authentication for my Apple ID and have handoff turned on, the code pops up on the mac where I'm seeking the two factor. Seems like it renders the two-factor worthless. Isn't the point it have it go to another device, separate from the login device?

I guess the obvious solution is to not have handoff on the mac?

Comment: Why does that make the two-factor worthless? Do you expect an attacker to have access to your Mac? The point is not to have the second factor go to a different device, it’s to have it go to a device that you have said is yours.

Comment: @MikeScott I already said this device is mine, why bother to send the code to it?